# How to redirect domain path to other domain path using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

The domains below are just sample domaains.
I want to redirect mydomain.com/test/ (wildcard) to google.com/dl (wildcard)

I am using this codes

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/.*$ https://google.com/dl
```

But when i access https://example.com/test/hi it redirects to https://google.com/dl , instead of https://google.com/dl/hi

How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written with shown samples. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)/?$ https://google.com/dl/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: @Cyberlicious, could you please do let me know what is the link you are hitting? Also kindly do mention if you are seeing any errors etc too.

Comment: @Cyberlicious, This rule looks for if a URI starts from `test` then do redirect. So it will redirect like: `http://localhost:80/test/singh123` TO `https://google.com/dl/singh123` as per shown samples here.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I just forgot to removed my old htaccess rules. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Cyberlicious, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning on this great forum :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try, you will find 100% solution, you must add below 3 lines to project's root folder .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L][/php]
```

Comment: This is not an answer to what is actually asked.